# Laravel Redis Sentinel Session

Tags: laravel, session, redis, sentinel, predis

I'm looking to use redis sentinel to store laravel sessions.
I have set up redis this way:

When I use Laravel's Cache::put and do a dd(Redis::connection('cache-connection')->keys('*')).
I do have the new values that I wanted to cache.

However when I try to insert a new session value like this:
Session::put('dddd', 'test');
I get nothing new when I do a
dd(Redis::connection('session-connection')->keys('*')).
Moreover I could notice that I have the new value when I do a
dd(Session::all());

What I could have forgotten in the configuration of the sessions, I put you the configuration file below.

Thank you in advance for any help that would allow me to progress.
Configuration of database.php :

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
    'cache-connection' =>[
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',

    ],
      'options' => [
          'replication'=>'sentinel',
          'service'=>'***',
          'parameters' =>[
            'password' =>env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'database' =>0,
          ],
    ],

    'session-connection' =>[
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',
      'tcp://127.0.0.1:26379?timeout=0.1',

    ],
      'options' => [
          'replication'=>'sentinel',
          'service'=>'***',
          'parameters' =>[
            'password' =>env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'database' =>1,
          ],
    ],
],
```

Configuration of  sessions.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 525600),

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => 'session-connection',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc", "memcached", or "dynamodb" session drivers you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

In my .env  ihave this :

CACHE_DRIVER=redis

SESSION_DRIVER=redis

SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_CLIENT=predis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_PASSWORD=null

REDIS_PORT=6379

REDIS_DB=0

Comment: Check your `.env`; is there anything in there setting the session driver to something else?

Comment: Hello thanks for looking , ihave this in my .env

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answer is coming an year after the last activity but I was going through the same issue and figured out that's normal that redis is not returning anything about the session before the end of the request.

Session data are made persistent only after the whole middlewares pipiline.

see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L127

that's how it looks the default session middleware of laravel:

```
protected function handleStatefulRequest(Request $request, $session, Closure $next)
{
    // If a session driver has been configured, we will need to start the session here
    // so that the data is ready for an application. Note that the Laravel sessions
    // do not make use of PHP "native" sessions in any way since they are crappy.
    $request->setLaravelSession(
        $this->startSession($request, $session)
    );

    $this->collectGarbage($session);

    $response = $next($request);

    $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);

    $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);

    // Again, if the session has been configured we will need to close out the session
    // so that the attributes may be persisted to some storage medium. We will also
    // add the session identifier cookie to the application response headers now.
    $this->saveSession($request);

    return $response;
}
```

I hope this helps ;)